# How would you do a timer on MPLAB C18 Compiler?

Tags: c

I am using MPLAB C18 Compiler with PIC18 and I was wondering if I can see an example showing how timers work. I am doing microcontroller programming using C but I don't really know how to do a timer. All I want to see is a timer that starts counting the time in seconds when the program opens up.

I appropriate your time!

Comment: a timer is just a loop + counter where the loop body execution time is known.

Comment: @MitchWheat, What your saying makes sense. An example would be everything I ever need.

Comment: @MitchWheat doesn't the PIC have at least one hardware timer?

Comment: most systems have a hardware timer (in which case its a counter incremented at a known rate...)

Comment: What have you tried? Which research have you done prior to asking this question? Which book are you reading?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, I haven't tried anything other than Googling and jumping from one forum to another to see examples. At this point not a lot of things make sense to me. If you have a book that you recommend to read, I would be more than happy to take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @Ammar Is that how you're learning C? It doesn't seem like a very successful way to learn...

Comment: The manual for your "C compiler" is very interesting... "*String literals are placed in program memory and so must be assigned to variables of type '`rom char *`'. However, assigning one to a pointer to data memory does not generate a diagnostic. For example:
  `char *s = "hello world";`

Any references through 's' will result in indeterminate behavior.*"